# TypeORM: What's difference between @Unique decorator and { unique: true } in column options?

Tags: typeorm

In TypeORM you have the possibility to set a unique flag in the column options, or to set column(s) to unique for the entity.

When would you use which, and what's the difference there?

`@Unique(["firstName"])`

https://typeorm.io/#/decorator-reference/unique

```
@Column({ unique: true })
firstName: string;
```

https://typeorm.io/#/decorator-reference/column

Comment: There is also `@Index({ unique: true })`

Answer (score 68, accepted):

As written in the docs `@Unique` can only be applied to entire entities, not to a single column. For readability, I prefer for simple constraints `@Column({ unique: true })` because it sits just on top of the affected variable name.

Another advantage of the `@Unique` syntax is the multi-column constraint ability. You can define multiple columns as one unique constraint: `@Unique(["firstName", "secondName"])`. This is not possible with the `@Column` decorator.

Finally, you can set a name for a particular constraint, when using `@Unique` decorator. The following single column constraint definition is functional equal, except `@Unique` sets a human readable name (Attention: `@Unique` expects the entity variable field name, not the actual database column name):

```js
@Unique('my_unique_constraint', ['firstName'])  // make firstName unique
export class PersonEntity {

   @Column({ unique: true })   // make firstName unique, too; decide which to chose
   firstName: string;
...
```

Comment: Is it possible to set the constraint name when using `@Column({ unique: true }) `?

Comment: @Ari I don't think so, since there is no such property in the ColumnOptions https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/941b584ba135617e55d6685caef671172ec1dc03/src/decorator/options/ColumnOptions.ts